# Is this use of "none" correct?

Tags: word-usage, concision

After detailing some strange results, I want to write something like

"Such apparent concern is no problem in practice as ..."

As I start to explain those results. My intuition was first

> [...]. Such apparent concern is none in practice as [...]

Which is more concise, less repetitive and sounds very natural to me (not native English speaker), but is it correct to use "none" this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**'none'**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/none#h70129007904160) is a *pronoun* (like 'he','she', 'it', or 'they') meaning 'not one', 'not any' or 'no one', so can not be used to describe an attribute (absence) of 'concern'.

Perhaps it would be better to untangle the sentence, putting the 'results' back in charge. For example:

'The results are of no concern in practice, as....'

or, to draw the contrast:

'The results, though anomalous, are of no practical concern, as..'